# Compare tables in VBA Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to compare two tables in VBA access to see if there are any new clients in one that need to be added to another. I am starting to develop the comparison loop but for some reason it isn't working.  It is saying the client ID field has a value of 6 for all the records in the one table, which is not true.  I'm not sure if I'm referencing it right in the `If` statement.  Any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

```
dte = InputBox("What date was the Data Dump run?", "Please Input a date")

tableName = "FN_DataDump_ALL_" & dte
Set dataDump = db.OpenRecordset(tableName, dbOpenDynaset, dbEditAdd)
Set clientTable = db.OpenRecordset("Clients", dbOpenDynaset, dbEditAdd)
With dataDump
    .MoveFirst
    Do
    If dataDump("[Client ID]") <> clientTable("[Client ID]") Then
         MsgBox (dataDump("[Client ID]"))
    clientTable.MoveNext
    Else: MsgBox ("Match.")
    .MoveFirst
End If
    Loop Until .EOF
End With
```

UPDATE:

For some reason VBA keeps saying it can't find the table DataDump, when it's opening correctly and everything.  I throws this error when it trys to run the SQL so I think there is something wrong with my statement.

```
Set db = CurrentDb


dte = InputBox("What date was the Data Dump run?", "Please Input a date")

tableName = "FN_DataDump_ALL_" & dte
Set DataDump = db.OpenRecordset(tableName, dbOpenDynaset, dbEditAdd)
Set clientTable = db.OpenRecordset("Clients", dbOpenDynaset, dbEditAdd)


MySQL = "SELECT DISTINCT CL.[Client ID] " & _
        "INTO Clients " & _
        "FROM Clients AS CL " & _
        "Where CL.[Client ID] NOT IN (SELECT DD.[Client ID] FROM  DataDump AS DD) "
```

UPDATE #2:

Now it is saying I have a syntax error and I am really confused as to what it is.

```
"Where CL.[Client ID] NOT IN (SELECT DD.[Client ID] ""FROM"" &  tableName ""as DD"") "
```

Comment: Does your database include a table or query named *DataDump*?

Comment: Not that name specifically but I opened it in VBA using that name so it shouldn't matter right?

Comment: OK, I see.  *DataDump* is a recordset object.  No, you can't `SELECT FROM` a recordset.

Comment: Oh I see. So I should change it to the table name it is in the database?

Comment: Yes, I think you want to use the value of your *tableName* variable there.

Comment: Ok. tableName is a string, will that matter?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your last comment.  I meant when you build your *MySQL* string, include your *tableName* string like in this stripped down example: `"FROM " & tableName & " AS DD"`

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Now it is giving me a syntax error in the line in Update #2. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Looks like a lot of quotation marks.  Put a break in the code, go to the "Immediate" window and type ?MySQL.  Make sure it returns a proper query string.  Your Update #2 should look like: "Where CL.[Client ID] NOT IN (SELECT DD.[Client ID] FROM " &  tableName " as DD)"

Comment: It works but it looks like it is including the "as" when it tries to open the table because it says this is the table name "FN_DataDump_ALL_11032014as" Why is this?

Comment: Gotta be an errant quotation mark somewhere.  Oh crap, I just realized I left off an & above.  There should be an & after tableName.  See the way HansUp did it?  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you've got a **.MoveFirst** where you should have a **.MoveNext**

However, a better way would be to use a NOT IN query.  I would do this:

```
tableName = "FN_DataDump_ALL_" & dte
Set dataDump = db.OpenRecordset(tableName, dbOpenDynaset, dbEditAdd)
Set clientTable = db.OpenRecordset("Clients", dbOpenDynaset, dbEditAdd)

MySQL = "SELECT DISTINCT CL.[Client ID] " & _
    "INTO TempClients " & _
    "FROM Clients AS CL " & _
    "Where CL.[Client ID] NOT IN (SELECT DD.[Client ID] FROM " & tableName & " AS DD) "

DoCmd.RunSQL (MySQL)
```

Now you've got your list of Client IDs in the dataset called "rec".  This is going to be more efficient than looping through every record and comparing IDs, unless your tables are pretty small and then the difference in proficiency will be negligible.

Comment: Thank you! One question, would I be able to then insert those into the clients table using an `INTO` statement? If so, where would I put that?

Comment: Depends on if the table exists or not.  You either use INSERT INTO or SELECT blah blah INTO.  And yes, you can easily add that to MySql but then you'd need a DoCmd.RunQuery because it would turn it into an Action Query.

Comment: SELECT ... INTO is if the table exists, INSERT INTO is if the table doesn't.  If you're using INSERT INTO, it will precede the SELECT statement.  If you're using SELECT ... INTO then the INTO part will come before the FROM clause.

Comment: Take a look at this link for an example (if you look on the left side of the page, you'll also see a link to an INSERT INTO statement): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208934(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thank you! In this case, I would put it before the first `FROM` correct?

Comment: Yes, that should do it.

Comment: Could you help me with the error I posted above? @Johnny-Bones

Comment: It might not like the dataset reference.  Instead of using "DataDump" in the query, try using "& TableName &".  Know what I mean?

Comment: Thats what I did. See the second update. That gives me a syntax error.

Comment: See my update above.  One big problem is you can't write to the same table name as you're reading from.  I changed it to TempClients above.  Plus I fixed your table variable name.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Johnny that a query is a better option.  Microsoft Access actually has a built in query builder to do this and has made a tutorial which can be found at the link below.  This obviously doesn't directly translate to VBA but you can build off of the query or use it in your VBA code.

[Find records without matches](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/compare-two-tables-and-find-records-without-matches-HA010205132.aspx)